# Showing youtube video tiles in Lightning web components

Tags: lightning-web-components, csp

I am currently migrating a vf page into Lightning web component, the vf page used to show the youtube video tiles on the page.
But when I am converting it into a LWC component then it is throwing error related to **Content Security Policy** . 
I don't know about any other way to implement the same feature into LWC.

This is the error I am facing.

> Refused to load plugin data from 'httpss://www.youtube.com/v/hJMszNULHJc' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "object-src 'self'

Comment: Hi, have you tried adding https://www.youtube.com/ to your Trusted CSP https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=csp_trusted_sites.htm&type=5 ?

Comment: It will not work event it is added to Trusted sites. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.js_api_calls

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify the link from 'https://www.youtube.com/{videoId}' to "'https://www.youtube.com/{videoId}'" -- so all you need to add is the (" ") in the link.